# how to get a tab through the tab's attribute text in TabPane in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I want get a tab through the tab's attribute `text`, but I cannot find a native method. So I writed a class to implement the purpose.
Question:
- I want to know if there is a native method for that purpose?
- Is there a better implementation?

Thanks!

```

```
    package pre.huangjs.tabpane;

    import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
    import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
    import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by huangjs on 2018/4/9.
     */
    public class TabPaneExpansion {
        private TabPane tabPane;
        private HashMap<String, Tab> tabsMap;

        public TabPane getTabPane() {
            return tabPane;
        }

        public void setTabPane(TabPane tabPane) {
            this.tabPane = tabPane;
        }

        public TabPaneExpansion() {
            this.tabPane = new TabPane();
            this.tabsMap = new HashMap<>();
            initial();
        }

        public TabPaneExpansion(TabPane tabPane) {
            this.tabPane = tabPane;
            this.tabsMap = new HashMap<>();
            initial();
        }

        private void initial() {
            tabPane.getTabs().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Tab>() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends Tab> c) {
                    while (c.next()) {

                        // if elements were added into list, the elements's text
                        // and the elements themselves need to be added into HashMap
                        if (c.wasAdded()) {
                            List<? extends Tab> addedTabs = c.getAddedSubList();
                            for (Tab tab : addedTabs) {
                                tabsMap.put(tab.getText(), tab);
                            }
                        }

                        // if elements were removed from list, the elements's text
                        // and the elements themselves need to be removed from HashMap
                        if(c.wasRemoved()){
                            List<? extends Tab> removedTabs = c.getRemoved();
                            for(Tab tab : removedTabs){
                                tabsMap.remove(tab.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        public boolean addTab(Tab tab) {
            return this.tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }

        public boolean addTabs(Tab... tabs) {
           return this.tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tabs);
        }

        public boolean removeTab(String text){
            return this.tabPane.getTabs().remove(getTabByText(text));
        }



  public Tab getTabByText(String text) {
        return tabsMap.get(text);
    }
}
```

```

Comment: Why not just remove the `Tab` from the `HashMap` in `removeTab(String text)` and add `Tab` to `HasMap` in `addTab(Tab tab)/ addTabs(Tab... tabs)`?

Comment: I think this question would have been better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Given that you're not going to have a huge number of tabs in a tab pane, and probably aren't going to be repeatedly removing tabs from the tab pane (at least not very often), I don't think it would be too bad just to do `tabPane.getTabs().removeIf(tab -> tab.getText().equals("..."));`. this would iterate through the list, rather than using a hashmap lookup, but unless you demonstrate the performance is an issue, I think I'd prefer this.

Comment: @Sedrick. I  did not remove the Tab from the HashMap in removeTab(String text), because I want get a return value like the native method `remove(...)`

Comment: @James_D. the idea is so good, thanks!